# Linking to a specific section in package-info.java

Tags: javadoc

How can I link to a specific section in a `package-info.java` file from Javadoc in other places?

The section could specified with a `<a name="section-name">...` tag, then the produced link should have a `... /package-summary.html#section-name` URL. But other ways of specifying sections are also interesting.

Requirements:

1. It must be possible to link from packages other than the one documented with `package-info.java` file.
2. URLs relative to the link source (like `..\..\p1\p2\package-info.java`) can not be used, since they would be so hard to maintain.
3. The link should (preferable) be understood not only by a web browser but also by IDEs (most importantly Eclipse) in their auto-generated, pop-up rendering of Javadoc.

   I think the only way to achieve this would be to not use `href` and instead use`{@linkplain}`, but I can't figure about how to specify a section.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do this with a `href` and the `@{docRoot}` tag:

```
<a href="{@docRoot}/p1/p2/package-summary.html#section-name">Section Name</a>
```

This doesn't fulfil requirement 3 though, since in Eclipse following such a link opens a web browser instead of the build in Javadoc viewer. So if anyone finds another solution I'd be grateful.